# error while setting up meanjs project using yo generator

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean

This error is seen when I try to setup meanjs project using `yo meanjs`

> WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"}
>   (current: {"node":"5.4.1","npm":"3.5.3"})

Initially I had not updated node and npm and same error showed. After updating node and npm, again same error is showing.

Comment: What version was node before the update?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage multiple versions of Node via [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Once you've installed `nvm`, install a version of Node that matches `karma`'s requirements (`{"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"}` ). You can then switch to that version of Node whenever you're working on the project.

I would recommend, however, that you obtain the most recent version of the [meanjs generator](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs) which is compatible with the `0.5.3` version of Node.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by choosing version of meanjs, `master` instead of `0.4.1`